# multiple quartz jobs overriding each other

Tags: java-8, quartz-scheduler

I have two quartz jobs A and B, each supposed to run in a completely separate process but the quartz tables are shared.

When I start B after A, A gets dropped and B is created in `quartz.qrtz_job_details`

Do I need to create separate triggers to avoid this situation?

Comment: Each of your job should have their own triggers. A single job can have multiple triggers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to same instance name for both the jobs. Once I separated the instance name, both jobs ran fine independently.